# SSRS Image filter

Tags: image, reporting-services

I have an SSRR report that has an image field.

The image source is external i.e. upload from a file.

Sometimes the file does not exist.

How can I filter these records that has no image out?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e0009c05-654f-4926-b20e-d90fd703785d/check-existence-of-image?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: https://powerbloggerbi.com/2016/03/14/ssrs-report-with-image-if-not-exist-the-image/